# Notepad++ Remove two or more spaces

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to remove occurrences of two or more spaces in a row in my dataset using regex with find and replace in Notepad++. I am aware that `([\s]+)([\s]+)` would probably do the job, however it would also remove tabs and I only want to remove two or more consecutive occurrences of spaces.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `\s` means any whitespace, but how about simply " " (that is, an empty space literal, or `/ {2,}/`)?

Comment: Are you looking for `[ ]{2,}`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xsA3eB/2 updated

Answer (score -1):

Replace \s{2,} with nothing, using the Regular Expression search mode.

Comment: As OP mentioned, he is aware of this solution. He only wants to remove spaces, not any whitespaces.

Comment: When I tested this in Notepad++ using a combination of tabs and spaces, my above answer only found the spaces and skipped the tabs.